# Length of a curve and calculus

Tags: calculus

While finding the length of a curve, we assume an infinitesimal right triangle, of width $dx$ and height $dy$, so arc length is ${\sqrt{dx^2 + dy^2}}$. But my question is that actually the curve is not having such a triangle the curve is continuously changing according to function,  not linearly. So, there will be an error in the length of a small part of the arc. Though this error may be neglected for small part but when we integrate over the whole curve the error will be finite. So, why don't we encounter the error that arises due to this part? Please explain in easy language I am just a beginner in calculus.

Comment: Kindly use MathJax to properly format the question.

Comment: If you break up the curve into more and more triangles, the accuracy becomes closer and closer until the length of the hypotenuses of the triangles equal to the length of the curve. That is why there is usually a limit as $n$ approaches infinity in front of a summation of the triangle hypotenuse lengths. This is the basis of how to find the length of a curve, similar to how the intuition for Riemann integration is breaking up the area into infinitely many rectangles of infinitesimally small width and height of $f(x)$.

Comment: It seems you are just starting out in calculus. You need to develop concepts like limit, infinimum, supremum before a rigorous definition can be given for length, area etc. Just take calculus one step at a time. Try to follow some intro level book for real analysis.

Comment: What is $dy/dx$? If $dx=0$ then it would imply to divide by zero. You really need the concept of limit...

Comment: OP's concerns are legit and they are not entirely addressed by the current comments/answers. Indeed a similar argument for surface areas fails to hold: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_lantern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can approximate the continuous curve with consecutive chords drawn from point to pint on it. The length of these chords will be given by pythagoreous formula. As you progressively draw smaller and smaller chords, the sum of the length of these chords tends to a number which is taken as the length of the curve.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's best to not think of $dx$ to be infinitesimal small, but instead to be just small but finite. Then there will be some error, as you correctly observed. Now, what happens if you instead choose a $dx$ which is only half as big? Well, intuitively, the error gets smaller. Now, choose a $dx$ which is again half as big, and then again and again. The error gets smaller and smaller and, in the limit, approaches zero. And this limit is how you define the length of the curve, no infinitesimals involved.

There are of course some simplifications in the description above: when making $dx$ smaller, the error not necessarily becomes smaller. However, it is sufficient if the error "eventually" becomes "sufficiently smaller" if you only continue to decrease $dx$. Also, of course, you want that the error approaches zero independently if you split $dx$ into two, three or $\pi$ parts every step...

Comment: A bit of handwaving here: how comes that this argument applies to curves but does not apply to surfaces (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_lantern)?